# How to change default new line character in R

Tags: r

All of the R output that I save to files, regardless of function used, uses the `\r\n` as characters for new lines. Is there a way to modify this default so that the text output only has `\n`?

Comment: What are you using to save your files?

Comment: Anything.. writeLines(), write(), write.csv(). Even if I do file('test.txt', "w"); cat('a', '\n', 'a', '\n', 'a', '\n', 'a', '\n', file = 'test.txt'), I find '\r\n' at the end of each line when I open the file with Notepad++

Comment: It's not what I get (R3.6.2/x86_64/Debian10)... See this https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-December/263786.html, looks like you can use `eol` in  `write.table()`, `cat()`, maybe other. Maybe worth adding the output of `sessionInfo()` so that others can further help.

Comment: I am wondering if there is a way to modify the default end-of-line character rather than specifying it whenever I output things. Also, opening files as ```'wb'``` still adds ```\r``` to each line.

R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Comment: I might be wrong but AFAIK, there are no options to control eol (see `options()`). A simple way to deal with this would be to have your own function with the expected behavior (e.g. `mycat <- function(...) cat(..., eol='\n')`) and then you could store it in your .Rprofile (see http://www.onthelambda.com/2014/09/17/fun-with-rprofile-and-customizing-r-startup/). That said, there might be a better way.